# Polymer, prevent label changing

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer, label

In a Polymer project I have drop-down menu, menu items serves as a buttons to evaluate popup menu. But when I click on item menu main label is getting changed to chosen item (see in pictures). How can I prevent label changing to selected one in paper-drop-down-menu.

`

```
<template>
    <iron-ajax auto url={{json_url}} last-response="{{list}}"></iron-ajax>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="{{title}}" no-animations  >

        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" aria-readonly="true">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}" as="v">
                <paper-item style="width: 100px" aria-readonly="true">{{v.name}}</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
</template>
```

`

[image: Drop down menu, not yet clicked on item. Fixed label needs to be Actions]

[image: Clicked on "Add" label got changed from "Actions" to "Add". How to prevent this?]

Comment: The label changes when selected. It's not treated as a link.

Comment: Is there anyway to build drop-down menu which will not change its label when  item is clicked ?

Comment: Think we're going to need to see some code first

Comment: Ok I'll post it right now.

Comment: This code is the implementation of what you see in pictures.

Answer (score 0):

After many desperate experiments I found solution. IMPORTATNT don't forget to include

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
```

Also this is full list if imports of below code.

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
```

This is the actual logic

```
<paper-menu>
        <paper-submenu>
            <paper-item class="menu-trigger">Some title</paper-item>
            <paper-menu class="menu-content">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="some list" as="v">
                    <paper-item style="width: 100px">{{v.name}}</paper-item>
                </template>
            </paper-menu>
        </paper-submenu>
    </paper-menu>
```